# Jenkins active choice plugins and scriptler plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I see that both Jenkins  **ActiveChoice** plugins and **Scriptler** plugin are being deprecated. I know how to download them. 
My question is what is the alternatives for Active Choice parameter? 
What is the alternative of using Scriptler in Jenkins? 
Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki
From 1.68 (February 09 2018)
Un-deprecated support for the Active Choices Plugin, but removed support for Scriptler scripts (JENKINS-48121)